# unable to load video - python opencv argparse

Tags: python, opencv, video, load, argparse

I'm toying around with [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/) from PyImageSearch on object tracking using openCV. 
In the template they provide, there is a line that lets you load your own video by adding arguments to `argparse`.

```
import argparse

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,
    help="path to input video")                                        #<--- here
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tracker", type=str, default="kcf",
    help="csrt")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Here, I substitute  `help="path to input video"` by `help="~/Users/my/path/to/video.mp4"`:

```
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,
    help="~/Users/my/path/to/video.mp4")
```

It is not working.
The template code opens your webcam if no video is provided, which is what happens for me. Therefore, there is no error message either.

I have checked that the path is correctly spelled.
Does anybody know how I can load a video using this parsing method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"help" - it's help message but no the path to video. You must start your python script with argument **-v=~/Users/my/path/to/video.mp4**

Answer (score 0):

The script is meant to run in the Command line, **not** in your IDE (e.g. Pycharm, Spyder). So the way to run it is:

1) Open Terminal

2) `$ cd ~/path/where/object/tracking/script/is/stored`

3) `$ python3 opencv_object_tracking.py -v=~/my/path/to/video.mp4 -t=csrt`